# How to upload multiple images to a django product model using DRF

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

Currently I am able to upload only 1 image per product.

**My Model**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,
                              default='/placeholder.png')
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    numReviews = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    countInStock = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
```

This is my **serializer**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reviews = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_reviews(self, obj):
        reviews = obj.review_set.all()
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(reviews, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

**This is the views file**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getProduct(request, pk):
    product = Product.objects.get(_id=pk)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I am trying to also upload the images to a folder which has same product name if possible.

Comment: You have to modify your model as well as your serializer also. I am just putting some suggestions in the answer section. Just take a look, I hope that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to upload multiple images for each product you have to modify your model as you have already designed. Let's see:

**Your Product model should look like this-**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.DecimalField(
             max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    mum_of_reviews = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, 
                    default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(
    max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    stock_counter = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, 
                    default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
```

Let's create a new model to add multiple images for each product-

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
              null=True, related_name='product_images')
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,
                          default='/placeholder.png')
```

Let's write the serializer for them

```
class ProductImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = '__all__'

class ProductRetriveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reviews = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    images = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

   class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = '__all__'

  def get_reviews(self, obj):
      reviews = obj.review_set.all()
      serializer = ReviewSerializer(reviews, many=True)
      return serializer.data

  def get_images(self, obj):
      images = obj.product_images.all()
      return ProductImageSerializer(images, many=True)

 class ProductCreationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     images = ProductImageSerializer(many=True, required=False)

     class Meta:
         model = Product
         fields = '__all__'
```

Let's write the API for creating a product with multiple images

```
class ProductCreateAPIView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)
    serializer = ProductCreationSerializer

    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        images = request.data.get('images', [])
        request.data.pop('images')
        serialized_data = self.serializer(data=request.data)
        product_obj = None
        if serialized_data.is_valid():
            product_obj=Product.objects.create(**serialized_data.validated_data)
  
       if product_obj and len(images) > 0:
           for image_data in images:
               image_data['product_id'] = str(product_obj._id)
               product_image_serialized_data = ProductImageSerializer(data=image_data)
            if product_image_serialized_data.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
              product_image_obj = ProductImage.objects.create(**product_image_serialized_data.validated_data)

    # Write your necessary code if needed
    return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I have at least tried to make you understand the way you will upload multiple images.Best of luck :)

Comment: There seems to be an issue with this line
product_image_obj = ProductImage.objects.create(**product_image_serialized_data.validated_data)

and 

return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

Comment: You can debug where the issue is being produced, unpack the data `product_image_serialized_data.validated_data` and check the data is corresponding to the `ProductImage` model fields.

Comment: Is it possible to create the same in function-based view as all my views are function-based.

Comment: Definitely possible and I am going to add in answer section

Comment: ok thank you, will check for the update..